# Scipy: Pearson's correlation always returning 1

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, correlation, pearson

I am using Python library scipy to calculate Pearson's correlation for two float arrays. The returned value for coefficient is always 1.0, even if the arrays are different. For example:

```
[-0.65499887  2.34644428]
[-1.46049758  3.86537321]
```

I am calling the routine in this way:

```
r_row, p_value = scipy.stats.pearsonr(array1, array2)
```

The value of `r_row` is always 1.0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Pearson's correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) is a measure of how well your data would be fitted by a linear regression. If you only provide it with two points, then there is a line passing exactly through both points, hence your data perfectly fits a line, hence the correlation coefficient is exactly 1.

Answer (score 6):

I think that pearson correlation coefficient always returns `1.0` or `-1.0` if each array has just two elements, since you can always draw a perfect straight line through the two points.Try it with arrays of length 3 and it will work:

```
import scipy
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

x = scipy.array([-0.65499887,  2.34644428, 3.0])
y = scipy.array([-1.46049758,  3.86537321, 21.0])

r_row, p_value = pearsonr(x, y)
```

Result:

```
>>> r_row
0.79617014831975552
>>> p_value
0.41371200873701036
```

Comment: This wrong, you have to make sure that the mean of all the values in the arrays x and y is 0. Otherwise the co-relation will be wrong